# .net core using https/ssl. Do i have to redirect?

Tags: asp.net-core

Ive created a website in dotnet core now. The site is live in, and hosted in azure. Ive set up the ssl sertificate, and binded it to the site.

Is there anything i have to do in web.config or startup to make ssl work?

I cant see the site using https. Will i have to redirect in startup?

Here is what i ended up with:

inside startup.cs, configure()

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.IsHttps)
                {
                    await next();
                }
                else
                {
                    var withHttps = "https://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.Path;
                    context.Response.Redirect(withHttps);
                }
            });
```

Comment: When you browse the site using https - what response do you get? (what do you see, http status code etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in startup you can configure the entire site to require https like this:

EDITED: to show how to only require https in production but note that you can easily also use https in development

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    environment = env;

}


public IHostingEnvironment environment { get; set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {

        if(environment.IsProduction())
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
         }

    });
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Can i check if the site is running on localhost or not in ConfigureServices()?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you could enable it only in production

Comment: in startup it would not be ideal to try to base logic on hostname like localhost since that is a per request thing not a startup thing, you could use a configuration setting or an environment as shown

Answer (score 1):

With release Asp NET Core 1.0.0 update your Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddMvc();

    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
    });

    // ...
}
```